# Deleting bytes from a io.ReadWriteSeeker(via file)

Tags: go

Let's say I have an io.ReadWriteSeeker that is reading an writing from a certain file.

At some point I decide I want to remove some bytes from the file (specifically the end) and reduce its length.

Whats the right way to go about this?

- I can't just overwrite it by seeking because I want to end up with a shorter file.
- io.CopyN will similarly not work (as src is smaller than dest)

Comment: That interface does not define any behaviour around truncating the data. You're going to have to create a new interface that add such a method, or work on a specific type like `*os.File`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `io.ReadWriteSeeker` value also supports a `Truncate` method, like an *os.File value.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func truncate(rws io.ReadWriteSeeker, size int64) error {
    type Truncater interface {
        Truncate(size int64) error
    }
    t, ok := rws.(Truncater)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("truncate: unable to truncate")
    }
    return t.Truncate(size)
}

func main() {
    filename := `/tmp/truncate.test.file`
    f, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    n, err := f.Write([]byte("test data"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))

    // truncate io.ReadWriteSeeker
    err = truncate(f, int64(n-1))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }

    data, err = ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
    os.Remove(filename)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/pp4IUSoKo4M

Output:

```
test data
test dat
```

Comment: Hey Peter, this works but I am unable to understand why. I probably just need to learn more about interfaces & go, but what function exactly is "Truncate(size int64) error" calling?

Is it somehow accessing the original *os.File.Truncate? Or is there another Truncate that I missed in the docs?